# subsetting dataframe by 3 consecutive days with related value

Tags: r, date, subset

I have an example dataframe:

```
       Date      p
4   2001-01-04  6.9
5   2001-01-05  4.5
6   2001-01-06  5.9
8   2001-01-08 15.8
24  2001-01-24  1.3
25  2001-01-25  4.6
26  2001-01-26 13.0
27  2001-01-27 45.1
32  2001-02-01  5.0
36  2001-02-05 21.9
37  2001-02-06 25.4
40  2001-02-09  1.4
41  2001-02-10  1.9
44  2001-02-13  9.1
45  2001-02-14 23.0
46  2001-02-15  8.8
53  2001-02-22  1.1
59  2001-02-28 24.8
```

I want to subset dataframe when there is 3 consecutive days with their related p values such as dates:`(2001-01-04,2001-01-05,2001-01-06)` with their p values`(6.9,4.5,5.9)`.I have huge dataframe which I wrote part of it here and I need only 3 consecutive days to be selected.

Any help on the above problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The conditions that make your subset are very unclear.  How are the p-values in your example relevant to being subset?  And I'm guessing you mean 'contiguous' not 'continues'.

Comment: Your use of the English language seems to be a problem. Can you describe what you want to happen when there are three dates in sequence, the word being sequential or contiguous and not "continues". Do you want the last three dates of that sequence or all of the sequences with a run of dates greater than or equal to 3 dates?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to extract subsets of rows where there are three consecutive days, and to include the p value in the extracted subset. And perhaps also to indicate a grouping of these rows as being in the same three-day block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructs a diff() vector and picks out the runs with length >= 2. It then shift that vector back one and do a logical OR since the first item in a run will have a FALSE value for rle()$value==1

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)
dat$diff <- c(0, diff(dat$Date))
datrl <- rle(dat$diff)  # Inadvertently omitted this line in initial posting
grp <- rep(seq_along(datrl$lengths), datrl$lengths)* 
       rep(datrl$values==1, datrl$lengths)*
       rep(datrl$lengths>=2, datrl$lengths)
dat[ grp | c(grp[-1], 0) , ]

#----
>  dat[ grp | c(grp[-1], 0) , ][1:3.]
         Date    p diff
1  2001-01-04  6.9    0
2  2001-01-05  4.5    1
3  2001-01-06  5.9    1
5  2001-01-24  1.3   16
6  2001-01-25  4.6    1
7  2001-01-26 13.0    1
8  2001-01-27 45.1    1
14 2001-02-13  9.1    3
15 2001-02-14 23.0    1
16 2001-02-15  8.8    1
```

Comment: I think you forget to put one step I couldn't understand what is "datrl".can you write how you define "datrl"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want list of 3 consecutive date subsets.

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("Date      p\n2001-01-04  6.9\n2001-01-05  4.5\n2001-01-06  5.9\n2001-01-08 15.8\n2001-01-24  1.3\n2001-01-25  4.6\n2001-01-26 13.0\n2001-01-27 45.1\n2001-02-01  5.0\n2001-02-05 21.9\n2001-02-06 25.4\n2001-02-09  1.4\n2001-02-10  1.9\n2001-02-13  9.1\n2001-02-14 23.0\n2001-02-15  8.8\n2001-02-22  1.1\n2001-02-28 24.8"), 
    header = TRUE, colClasses = c("Date", "numeric"))

# find out which dates are 3rd consecutive dates. sel below is logical vector indicating such dates
sel <- c(0, diff(data$Date)) == 1 & c(0, 0, diff(data$Date, 2) == 2)

# get start and end dates
start <- which(sel) - 2
end <- which(sel)

# get all the 3 consecutive dates subsets
mapply(function(start, end) data[start:end, ], start, end, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
## [[1]]
##         Date   p
## 1 2001-01-04 6.9
## 2 2001-01-05 4.5
## 3 2001-01-06 5.9
## 
## [[2]]
##         Date    p
## 5 2001-01-24  1.3
## 6 2001-01-25  4.6
## 7 2001-01-26 13.0
## 
## [[3]]
##         Date    p
## 6 2001-01-25  4.6
## 7 2001-01-26 13.0
## 8 2001-01-27 45.1
## 
## [[4]]
##          Date    p
## 14 2001-02-13  9.1
## 15 2001-02-14 23.0
## 16 2001-02-15  8.8
##
```

Comment: That does duplicate the values where runs of more than three occur.

Comment: @DWin true. it's just assumption on my part OP wanted that. Your solution is good too